# Iterator returning Generic Collection - Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, generics, collections, iterator

I can write Iterators as follows:

```
enum Stage { case a, ab, end }

struct SetMaker<Input: Hashable>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
  var a,b: Input
  var stage = Stage.a

  init(a: Input, b: Input) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  }

  mutating func next() -> Set<Input>? {
    switch stage {
    case .a:    stage = .ab;   return Set<Input>([a])
    case .ab:   stage = .end;  return Set<Input>([a,b])
    case .end:                 return nil
    }
  }
}

let setMaker = SetMaker(a: "A", b: "B")
for x in setMaker {
  print(x)
}

struct ArrayMaker<Input: Hashable>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
  var a: Input
  var b: Input
  var stage = Stage.a

  init(a: Input, b: Input) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  }

  mutating func next() -> Array<Input>? {
    switch stage {
    case .a:    stage = .ab;   return Array<Input>([a])
    case .ab:   stage = .end;  return Array<Input>([a,b])
    case .end:                 return nil
    }
  }
}

let arrayMaker = ArrayMaker(a: "A", b: "B")
for x in arrayMaker {
  print(x)
}
```

The first returning a sequence of Sets and the second returning a sequence of Arrays.

These both work fine but I like to keep my code "DRY" (i.e. Don't Repeat Yourself).

So I'd like to do write something Generic that will allow construction of either.
My attempt is:

```
struct AnyMaker<Input: Hashable, CollectionType>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
  var a,b: Input
  var stage = Stage.a

  init(a: Input, b: Input) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  }

  mutating func next() -> CollectionType<Input>? {
    switch stage {
    case .a:    stage = .ab;   return CollectionType<Input>([a])
    case .ab:   stage = .end;  return CollectionType<Input>([a,b])
    case .end:                 return nil
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't compile.
Any help appreciated   :-)

Edit...

@Rob made a good suggestion which gets me part way there - see his answer.
But if I want the Collection to be a Set sometimes then there's an issue because Set is not RangeReplaceable.

To put it another way I've created a slightly different bit of code:

```
struct Pairs<C>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol
where C: RangeReplaceableCollection {

  var collection: C
  var index: C.Index

  init(_ collection: C) {
    self.collection = collection
    index = self.collection.startIndex
  }

  mutating func next() -> C? {
    guard index < collection.endIndex else { return nil }
    let element1 = collection[index]
    index = collection.index(after: index)
    guard index < collection.endIndex else { return nil }
    let element2 = collection[index]
    let pair = [element1,element2]
    return C(pair)
  }
}

do {
  print("Pairs from array")
  let array = ["A","B","C"]
  let pairs = Pairs(array) //This line is fine
  for pair in pairs {
    print(pair)
  }
}

do {
  print("Pairs from set")
  let set = Set(["A","B","C"])
  let pairs = Pairs(set) // This line causes error
  for pair in pairs {
    print(pair)
  }
}
```

The line "let pairs = Pairs(set)" generates an error:
"Argument type 'Set' does not conform to expected type 'RangeReplaceableCollection'"

So I need to work out how to instantiate a collection without using RangeReplaceableCollection?

Comment: Swift 2.2 is way obselete. You'll be hard pressed to get answers on a version so old that people can't even compile

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I'm writing in swift 4.2 so not sure why you are thinking Swift version is 2.2?

Comment: Just to note that as a result of Rob's answer, I edited my question and added extra details and code on the end of the question.  I wasn't quite sure whether this was the correct way to continue the conversation.  The alternative was to create an entirely new post.  If anyone reading this thinks that would have been better please let me know - I'm keen to follow recommended practice on this forum.

Comment: Your edit is fine and helpful. Set was part of the original question.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you want to return an arbitrary `Collection` which is extremely difficult in Swift because there is no promise that a `Collection` can be initialized. If instead the method `next()` returned `Collection.SubSequence?`, this would all be straightforward and match stdlib much more closely. Is it really critical that you return `[T]` rather than `ArraySlice<T>` (which is easier to generate and doesn't require copying)?

Comment: The things is that sometimes I want to return a Set instead of an Array so I can't use ArraySlice.  I've solved the problem of initializing a collection.  It's explained in my alternative answer.  It's actually surprisingly simple: protocol UsableCollection: Collection {
  init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Element == Element
}

extension Array: UsableCollection { }
extension Set: UsableCollection { }.

This then allows instantiating the Collection.  

Could also use:

UsableCollection: Collection {
  init()
}
I always forget how easy it is to extend existing types :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never restricted the type of `CollectionType`, so Swift doesn't know you can create one at all, let alone create one by passing an array. `Collection` itself doesn't promise any `init` methods, either. We need to go to `RangeReplaceableCollection` to get that:

```
struct AnyMaker<CollectionType>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol
where CollectionType: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    typealias Input = CollectionType.Element

    ...
}
```

Once you've done that, `next()` looks like this:

```
mutating func next() -> CollectionType? {
    switch stage {
    case .a:    stage = .ab;   return CollectionType([a])
    case .ab:   stage = .end;  return CollectionType([a,b])
    case .end:                 return nil
    }
}
```

Note that this returns `CollectionType?` not `CollectionType<Input>?`. Nothing about `CollectionType` requires that it take a type parameter, so we can't pass one. There's no way to express "takes a type parameter" even if we wanted it, but we don't want it. `CollectionType` just has to have some `Element`, and that's promised by `RangeReplaceableCollection`.

```
let anyMaker = AnyMaker<[String]>(a: "A", b: "B")
for x in arrayMaker {
    print(x)
}
```

---

Full code:

```
struct AnyMaker<CollectionType>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol
where CollectionType: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    typealias Input = CollectionType.Element
    var a,b: Input
    var stage = Stage.a

    init(a: Input, b: Input) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    mutating func next() -> CollectionType? {
        switch stage {
        case .a:    stage = .ab;   return CollectionType([a])
        case .ab:   stage = .end;  return CollectionType([a,b])
        case .end:                 return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob, This gets me part of the way there but I need CollectionType to sometimes be Set which is not RangeReplaceable.  I'll post an alternative answer with some new code to illustrate.

Comment: Instead of posting an alternative answer I edited my question.

Comment: I decided to say this is the Answer because it solved the primary part of my Problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even though Collection doesn't require an initialiser, Array and Set do have the initialiser we want:

```
init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Element == Element
```

so by creating a new procotol which requires this and then extending Array and Set with this protocol we can then assume that UsableCollections will have this initialiser and all works as required:

```
protocol UsableCollection: Collection {
  init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where S.Element == Element
}

extension Array: UsableCollection { }
extension Set: UsableCollection { }

struct Pairs<C: UsableCollection>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
  var collection: C
  var index: C.Index

  init(_ collection: C) {
    self.collection = collection
    index = self.collection.startIndex
  }

  mutating func next() -> C? {
    guard index < collection.endIndex else { return nil }
    let element1 = collection[index]
    index = collection.index(after: index)
    guard index < collection.endIndex else { return nil }
    let element2 = collection[index]
    let pair = [element1,element2]
    return C(pair)
  }
}

do {
  print("Pairs from array")
  let array = ["A","B","C"]
  let pairs = Pairs(array)
  for pair in pairs {
    print(pair)
  }
}

do {
  print("Pairs from set")
  let set = Set(["A","B","C"])
  let pairs = Pairs(set)
  for pair in pairs {
    print(pair)
  }
}
```